# SneakyJoystick - Movement by certain points/tiles

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I have SneakyJoystick up and running but I want to move my sprite tile by tile in a certain frequency ... I am pretty new to iphone programming and cocos2d so I don't exactly know how the whole SneakyJoystick thingy works. 
I got the code from a book and again: I just want my Sprite to move like in the game Pokèmon tile by tile...

```
-(void)initJoystickAndButtons {
    CGSize screenSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].winSize;
    CGRect joystickBaseDimensions =
    CGRectMake(0, 0, 128.0f, 128.0f);
    CGRect jumpButtonDimensions =
    CGRectMake(0, 0, 64.0f, 64.0f);
    CGRect attackButtonDimensions =
    CGRectMake(0, 0, 64.0f, 64.0f);
    CGPoint joystickBasePosition;
    CGPoint jumpButtonPosition;
    CGPoint attackButtonPosition;
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // The device is an iPad running iPhone 3.2 or later.
        CCLOG(@"Positioning Joystick and Buttons for iPad");
        joystickBasePosition = ccp(screenSize.width*0.0625f,screenSize.height*0.052f);
        jumpButtonPosition = ccp(screenSize.width*0.946f,screenSize.height*0.052f);
        attackButtonPosition = ccp(screenSize.width*0.947f,screenSize.height*0.169f);
    } else {
        // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
        CCLOG(@"Positioning Joystick and Buttons for iPhone");
        joystickBasePosition = ccp(screenSize.width*0.07f,
                                   screenSize.height*0.11f);
        jumpButtonPosition = ccp(screenSize.width*0.93f,
                                 screenSize.height*0.11f);
        attackButtonPosition = ccp(screenSize.width*0.93f,
                                   screenSize.height*0.35f);
    }

SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase *joystickBase = [[[SneakyJoystickSkinnedBase alloc] init] autorelease];
joystickBase.position = joystickBasePosition;
joystickBase.backgroundSprite =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"dpadDown.png"];
joystickBase.thumbSprite =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"joystickDown.png"];
joystickBase.joystick = [[SneakyJoystick alloc]initWithRect:joystickBaseDimensions];

leftJoystick = [joystickBase.joystick retain];
leftJoystick.isDPad = YES;
[self addChild:joystickBase];

SneakyButtonSkinnedBase *jumpButtonBase =[[[SneakyButtonSkinnedBase alloc] init] autorelease];
jumpButtonBase.position = jumpButtonPosition;
jumpButtonBase.defaultSprite =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"jumpUp.png"];
jumpButtonBase.activatedSprite =[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"jumpDown.png"];
jumpButtonBase.pressSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"jumpDown.png"];
jumpButtonBase.button = [[SneakyButton alloc]initWithRect:jumpButtonDimensions]; 
jumpButton = [jumpButtonBase.button retain];
jumpButton.isToggleable = NO;
[self addChild:jumpButtonBase];
SneakyButtonSkinnedBase *attackButtonBase =[[[SneakyButtonSkinnedBase alloc] init] autorelease];
attackButtonBase.position = attackButtonPosition;
attackButtonBase.defaultSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"handUp.png"];
attackButtonBase.activatedSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"handDown.png"];
attackButtonBase.pressSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"handDown.png"];
attackButtonBase.button = [[SneakyButton alloc]initWithRect:attackButtonDimensions];
attackButton = [attackButtonBase.button retain];
attackButton.isToggleable = NO;
[self addChild:attackButtonBase];

> }

    > -(void)applyJoystick:(SneakyJoystick *)aJoystick toNode:(CCNode *)tempNode forTimeDelta:(float)deltaTime{
    >     CGPoint scaledVelocity = ccpMult(aJoystick.velocity, 44.0f); // 1
    >     CGPoint newPosition = ccp(tempNode.position.x + scaledVelocity.x * deltaTime,tempNode.position.y + scaledVelocity.y * deltaTime);
    >     [tempNode setPosition:newPosition];
    >     if (jumpButton.active == YES) {
    >         CCLOG(@"Jump button is pressed.");
    >         if (attackButton.active == YES) {
    >             CCLOG(@"Attack button is pressed.");
    >         } }
    >      }

> 

    > # pragma mark -
    > # pragma mark Update Method

> -(void) update:(ccTime)deltaTime {
>     [self applyJoystick:leftJoystick toNode:dude
>            forTimeDelta:deltaTime];
>      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar for my game. There are many steps and cannot go much into detail.

**First** you need to know when is the joystick being used.

**Second** you need to interpet the direction of the joystick. For a game like Pokemon, you only need to check for up/down/right/left directions. It is possible to access the *degrees* of the joystick. Simply interpret the degrees like "if degrees are between -45 to 45, it means the joystick is mainly facing right" etc.

**Third** you will have to unlink the joystick from your player object. That tutorial, somewhere, makes you link both of them so that the joystick will automatically move the player. You have to undo that.

**Fourth** make up a schedule somewhere in your scene. The schedule will interpret the joystick direction (if it is being used), and will run a `CCMoveBy` action on the player. If the joystick directs to the right and the map's tile size is 32, then the `CCMoveBy` movement parameter would be (32,0). Remember to not run a nother action if the player is already running one.

There are many details and so much to polish. You better try to ask each thing individually instead of everything in one shot.